# Determining whether the problem of given a turing machine figuring out whether the language it accepts is the set of prime length inputs is R.E

Tags: turing-machines

I'm trying to figure out whether the following problem is R.E.?

Given a turing machine $M$ with alphabet $\Sigma$ is it the case that:

$L(M) = \{w \in \Sigma^* | |w| \space is \space prime\}$

I think I have a reduction from $HALT$ complement which is co - R.E. to the problem proving that it's not R.E. but I'm not entirely sure if it's correct (Define a new turing machine which on input y runs M on w for |y| steps and rejects if M halts on w in |y| steps, else perform sieve and accept iff |y| is prime) but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the definition of "R.E" that is used in this question?

Comment: A R.E.language is a language for which there exists a Turing machine (doesn't have to be a total Turing machine) accepting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your reduction is correct. Indeed, the reduction is clearly computable and furthermore if the original Turing machine $M$ halts on (the fixed) input $w$, then the set of words accepted by the new Turing machine $M'$ is a finite set of words (of prime length), while if $M$ does not halt on input $w$, then the words accepted by $M'$ are precisely those words which have prime length. Thus your problem is $coRE$-hard.

Let me also point out that it is in fact even harder than $coRE$-hard: it is $coRE^{RE}$-complete (here $coRE^{RE}$ is the complement of languages that can be enumerated by a Turing machine that has an oracle to the halting problem). The lower bound can be proved by reducing the following $coRE^{RE}$-hard problem to it: given a Turing machine $M$, determine whether it halts on every input. The reduction is very similar to the reduction that you already used. On input $w$, our Turing machine $M'$ simulates the given Turing machine $M$ on every input of length $|w|$, and if $M$ halts on every such input, then $M'$ accepts iff $|w|$ is prime.